# C# - How to get value of key in multidimensional JSON

Tags: c#, json

I'm very new to C# so please excuse me if i am asking silly question. I am using Newtownsoft json. (https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Here is my code:

```
public void SpawnPlayer(Dictionary<string, string> playerData, int cnnId)    
{

    string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(playerData, Formatting.None);
    Console.WriteLine(jsonData);
}
```

Here is what `jsonData` contains:

> {"1":"{\r\n  \"characterId\": 1,\r\n  \"connectionId\": 1,\r\n 
>   \"accountId\": 1,\r\n  \"name\": \"Riorage\",\r\n  \"level\": 2,\r\n 
>   \"characterRace\": 1,\r\n  \"characterClass\": 1,\r\n 
>   \"characterPosition\": {\r\n    \"x\": \"15.42661\",\r\n    \"y\":
>   \"7.477493\",\r\n    \"z\": \"-32.30045\",\r\n    \"map\": 1\r\n 
>   },\r\n  \"characterRotation\": {\r\n    \"x\": \"1\",\r\n    \"y\":
>   \"203\",\r\n    \"z\": \"1\"\r\n  },\r\n  \"charactrerInstance\":
>   {\r\n    \"instanceId\": 0,\r\n    \"groupId\": 0\r\n  },\r\n 
>   \"characterState\": 1,\r\n  \"characterMovementState\": 0,\r\n 
>   \"characterActionState\": 1,\r\n  \"characterEmotionState\": 1,\r\n 
>   \"lastOnline\": \"5.4.2018 г. 14:59:16\",\r\n  \"onlineTime\":
>   \"1\"\r\n}"}

I would like to know how can i reach the value of `1`,`CharacterPosition`,`x`.

I want to give these keys and receive an output `15.42661`

Is it even possible and if so how ?

Comment: You migth be interested to check this way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c/17842600#17842600

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below one:

```
string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(playerData, Formatting.None);
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dictionary<string,dictionary<string,object>>>(jsonData);
var x = data["1"]["CharacterPosition"].x;
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Comment: What if i have a class with the same structure as the json keys ?

Comment: then you can directly use it as `DeserializeObject<Class>` ..

Answer (score 0):

A similar way than what @Aman suggested, but letting `dynamic` handle the type on runtime:

```
dynamic d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{'1':{'characterId':1,'connectionId':1,'accountId':1,'name':'Riorage','level':2,'characterRace':1,'characterClass':1,'characterPosition':{'x':'15.42661','y':'7.477493','z':'-32.30045','map':1},'characterRotation':{'x':'1','y':'203','z':'1'},'charactrerInstance':{'instanceId':0,'groupId':0},'characterState':1,'characterMovementState':0,'characterActionState':1,'characterEmotionState':1,'lastOnline':'5.4.2018г.14:59:16','onlineTime':'1'}}");

Console.Write(d["1"].characterPosition.x);
```

But, you could always create you own class and call `DeserializeObject<Class>`

**Edit**: Check out this [class generator](http://json2csharp.com/)